# Select values in dataframe TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i want filter all data on condition `type` have contains() or subset() 'NCO - ETD' follow groupby date and id.

I wrote this code:

```
cond = 'NCO - ETD'
mask = data.groupby(['Date','Id'])['Type'].agg(set).apply(lambda x: any(x.issubset(cond)))
```

but **TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable**

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need subset use `list` from `cond` and remove `apply` with `any`:

```
mask = data.groupby(['Date','Id'])['Type'].agg(lambda x: set(x).issubset([cond]))
```

Or if need test substring create helper column and then test it at least one `True` per groups by `any`:

```
cond = 'NCO - ETD'
mask = (data.assign(new = data['Type'].str.contains(cond))
            .groupby(['Date','Id'])['new']
            .transform('any'))
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help. It works.